# mxGraphComponent in Applet

Tags: java, applet, runtimeexception, appletviewer, jgraphx

When i use mxGraphComponent in an applet, this applet run in appletviewer in eclipse but it don't run in any browser because it throws an ExceptionInInitializerError Exception.
Searching on the internet I have seen that mxGraphComponent should be run in application.

How can I solve this problem?

*Code example*

```
import javax.swing.JApplet;

import com.mxgraph.swing.mxGraphComponent;
import com.mxgraph.view.mxGraph;

public class ProvaApplet extends JApplet{
    public void init() {
        mxGraph g = new mxGraph();
        Object v1 = g.insertVertex(g.getDefaultParent(), null, "example1", 0, 0, 100, 30);
        Object v2 = g.insertVertex(g.getDefaultParent(), null, "example2", 200, 200, 100, 30);
        g.insertEdge(g.getDefaultParent(), null, "exampleedge", v1,v2);
        mxGraphComponent graph = new mxGraphComponent(g);
        getContentPane().add(graph);
    }
}
```

Comment: *"because it throws an ExceptionInInitializerError Exception"*  Copy/paste the stack trace as an [edit to the question](http://stackoverflow.com/posts/17336241/edit).  Ensure the [Java Console](http://www.java.com/en/download/help/javaconsole.xml) is configured to show for applets & JWS apps.  If there is no output at the default level, raise it and try again.

Comment: Cannot be answered without a stack trace.